# Select jquery elements except specific children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a simple question, but, I haven't found a clear answer in any of the question that I found. I modified a **JSFiddle** for my specific question.

I got this tiny code:

```
<ul>
    <li id='one'>Element 1</li>
    <li id='two'>Element 2</li>
    <li id='three'>Element 3</li>
    <li id='four'>Element 4</li>
    <li id='five'>Element 5</li>
</ul>
```

and this script should **return** the `ul` element excepting the first `li`:

```
$(function(){
    $("ul").not($('#one'))
});
```

Instead, it removes every li. What have I done wrong?

**EDIT:** In others words, I would like a selector which selects this, without removing the actual element (= inside a variable)

```
<ul>
    <li id='two'>Element 2</li>
    <li id='three'>Element 3</li>
    <li id='four'>Element 4</li>
    <li id='five'>Element 5</li>
</ul>
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/LVUMs/13/

Comment: "this script should remove the ul element excepting the first li" This makes no sense. If you remove the ul element, where is the first li going to go?

Comment: nowhere? My need is to return the ul containing every element without the first one.
I said "Remove", for illustration

Comment: Then you should have said "return", not "remove". What your code is doing is removing content.

Comment: sorry, edited question

Comment: Do you just want to remove first `li`? And what do you mean by return?

Comment: I want to return the ul excepting the first li. I edited the question, I'm very sorry for people not to understanding it, it's my fault.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/LVUMs/17/?

Comment: @sidney, then you just need `$("ul li:not(#one)")` or `$("ul li").not($('#one'))` heres example http://jsfiddle.net/wydWy/

Comment: @Satpal this is exactly what I need, do you have something nicer please :) ?

Comment: @sidney, You have it in variable `var ulexceptOneLi = $("ul li:not(#one)");` It will not remove actual element. In the above example I have used `$('div').append(ul);` thats why it got removed.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Use</s>

```
$("ul li").not($('#one')).remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MNf2v/)

OR

```
$("ul li:not(#one)").remove();
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzC2k/)

### EDIT

You need

```
var ulexceptOneLi = $("ul li:not(#one)");
```

or

```
var ulexceptOneLi = $("ul li").not($('#one'));
```

Comment: Thanks ,but I need to return ul containing those removed li.

Comment: Remove the sub elements and then return the object.

Comment: It doesn't work http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/25/1403266034-untitled.png

Comment: Well, I am beginning to think that what I'm seeking for is impossible then.
I don't want to rebuild a new `ul` element, I want to select that very `ul` element without it's first child (but not removing it, it's just in that variable), in order to perform operations on that `ul` element.
Thanks anyways

Comment: @Satpal, `$("ul :not(#one)")` doesn't render a ul containing the 4 li that I want, but it renders directly 4 li...

Comment: @sidney, Then use `$("ul").clone().remove('#one')` http://jsfiddle.net/F6Fbq/ Hope this helps ping me if it works

Comment: @Satpal , you are kind, but it doesn't work. I think that there is no possible solution.
Indeed, I simplified the issue I have by setting a simple code that you see here (ul and li situation)
However, what you suggests me cannot work, because I need to animate (jQuery animate function) the ul without that li. And if I animate the clone, it won't work out, because only the clone will be animated.
I upvoted your answer as sign of gratitude. For my case, I will, for now, remove entirely that li, perform my animation, and reappend that li.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVUMs/16/)**

```
$(function(){
    $("ul>li").not($('#one')).empty();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question I want to return the ul containing the removed li, not to simply remove them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to keep the `ul` in play:

```
$("ul li#one").remove();
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8x74/)...

If you're wanting to return a `ul` element with the removed element inside, try this:

```
function do_crazy_thing(){

  var removed = $("ul li#one").remove();

  return $('<ul></ul>').append(removed);

}

do_crazy_thing();
```

Here's [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8x74/1/)...

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/q8x74/2/) how you would then append your new `ul` element to the body...

Comment: I meant it doesn't work, because it doesn't return the ul element, it does remove it, but it isn't what I want

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need, do you have a nicer solution please?

Comment: what do you mean 'nicer'? :-)

Comment: Without having to remove and reappend, I'd like a selector selecting this inside the `removed` variable directly :)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to elaborate. What do you want the end result to be? The selector for the unwanted `li` element is simply `$("ul li#one")`...

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVUMs/23/)**

According to your question, your expected output is :

```
<ul>
    <li id='two'>Element 2</li>
    <li id='three'>Element 3</li>
    <li id='four'>Element 4</li>
    <li id='five'>Element 5</li>
</ul>
```

Check the demo.

### Edit :

```
$(function(){
    var removed = $("ul li:not(#one)");
});
```

OR

```
var op = $("ul :not(#one)");
```

Comment: nope, I'm expecting this output in a variable only, sorry
I change the question.. sorry for clarity

Comment: It doesn't work.
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/25/1403266034-untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

Please try below JS code

```
$(function(){
   var test= $("ul li").remove("#one");
});
```